# Server autoinstall encrypt voluem but prompt for password

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption, lvm

Here is what I want to accomplish:

During an "autoinstall", I want to create an lvm layout on top of an encrypted (dm_crypt) volume, but prompt for the encryption password during the install. Also, if there are multiple disks, let the user choose which disk to partition.

I can make "storage" an interactive section, but I'd like to enforce (or at least make it the default) that the root volume is encrypted, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think theres a way to cause the installer to do that.  What we've ended up with different autoinstall files for different hardware profiles.